# Changing variable values from another class

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I'd like to do something like this.

**Main class**

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class test 
{

 public static JFrame frame;
 public static JPanel panel;    
 public static JButton settings;
 public static int red = 10;
 public static int green = 100;
 public static int blue  = 10;
 
 public static void main( String[] args )
 {
    
  frame = new JFrame();
  frame.setSize(  100 , 100 );
    
  panel = new JPanel();
  panel.setBackground( new Color( red , green , blue) );
  frame.add(  panel );
  
  settings = new JButton( "settings" );
  panel.add( settings );
  settings.addActionListener( new settingsctionListener() );
  
  frame.setVisible( true );
    
 }

}
```

**Another class**

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class settingsctionListener implements ActionListener
{

 @Override
 public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e )
 {

  test.red = 100;
  test.green = 255;
  test.blue = 255;
  
 }

}
```

Don't know how to do that thing.

That another class should change variable values red green and blue to change the entire theme.

There is a method panel.setBackground(...), but that will only change the panel color. like to change the variables for entire theme.

Comment: You will most likely need to implement another function (`updateTheme(int r, int g, int b)`) to update the panel and any other element you want to update the color for. Simply changing the variable values of the static class `test` will not automatically update those elements.

Comment: @ ELinda Thank you. Yeah, but how to do that?

Comment: Please see elaborated answer below.

Answer (score 0):

- The panel and other elements are *not* automatically updated when the static variables `red`, `green`, and `blue` are updated. They need to be updated individually using their respective "set" methods.
- You need to add code for other UI elements. I only see the `JPanel` and that's the only one updated in `updateTheme`, but you may need to add other setter invocations.
- For style (not correctness): start classes with uppercase letters.

```java
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class EntryPoint {
    public static JFrame frame;
    public static JPanel panel;
    public static JButton settings;
    public static int red = 10;
    public static int green = 100;
    public static int blue  = 10;

    public static void updateTheme(int r, int g, int b) {
        panel.setBackground( new Color(r, g, b) );

        // Update any other UI elements (panels etc).
        // Update the static variables in case they're needed for some reason
        red = r;
        green = g;
        blue = b;
    }
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {

        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(  100 , 100 );

        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground( new Color( red , green , blue) );
        frame.add(  panel );

        settings = new JButton( "settings" );
        panel.add( settings );
        settings.addActionListener( new SettingsActionListener() );

        frame.setVisible( true );

    }

}
```

```java
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class SettingsActionListener implements ActionListener
{
    // Do not need Override if using ActionListener trait
    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e )
    {
        // invoke the static updateTheme method
        EntryPoint.updateTheme(100, 255, 255);
        System.out.println("Settings updated");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before coming to the final solutions, we should clean up your code a bit. Especially

- Do **NEVER** work with static variables (bad style - it's just not object oriented)
- Make your starting class inherit from JFrame

After having considered this, you have four ways to implement your ActionListener. A common way in Swing development is the use of anonymous classes. Then it will look like this:

```java
class SwingTest1 extends JFrame {
    
    final JPanel panel;
    final JButton settings;

    int red = 10;
    int green = 100;
    int blue = 10;

    private SwingTest1() {
        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(new Color(red, green, blue));
        add(panel);

        settings = new JButton("settings");
        panel.add(settings);

        // anonymous ActionListener class
        settings.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                red = 100;
                green = 255;
                blue = 255;
                panel.setBackground(new Color(red, green, blue));
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingTest1 frame = new SwingTest1();
        frame.setSize(100, 100);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Or you can make your class implement ActionListener as well:

```java
class SwingTest2 extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    
    final JPanel panel;
    final JButton settings;
    
    int red = 10;
    int green = 100;
    int blue = 10;

    private SwingTest2() {
        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(new Color(red, green, blue));
        add(panel);

        settings = new JButton("settings");
        panel.add(settings);

        // ActionListener as self-reference
        settings.addActionListener(this);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        this.red = 100;
        this.green = 255;
        this.blue = 255;

        panel.setBackground(new Color(red, green, blue));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingTest2 frame = new SwingTest2();
        frame.setSize(100, 100);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

If you really want to have two classes, work with a back reference to your Frame:

```java
class SwingTest3 extends JFrame {

    final JPanel panel;
    final JButton settings;
    
    int red = 10;
    int green = 100;
    int blue = 10;

    private SwingTest3() {
        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(new Color(100, 100, 10));
        add(panel);

        settings = new JButton("settings");
        panel.add(settings);

        // ActionListener with back reference
        settings.addActionListener(new SettingsListener(this));
    }
    
    public void setColor(int red, int green, int blue) {
        this.red = red;
        this.green = green;
        this.blue = blue;

        panel.setBackground(new Color(red, green, blue));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingTest3 frame = new SwingTest3();
        frame.setSize(100, 100);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

and the Listener class:

```java
class SettingsListener implements ActionListener {

    final SwingTest3 frame;

    public SettingsListener(SwingTest3 frame) {
        super();
        this.frame = frame;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        frame.setColor(100, 255, 255);
    }
}
```

Since Java 8, you can also use a Lamda expression as ActionListener. This makes your code more compact, but might be harder to read for beginners:

```java
class SwingTest4 extends JFrame {
    
    final JPanel panel;
    final JButton settings;

    private SwingTest4() {
        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(new Color(100, 100, 10));
        add(panel);

        settings = new JButton("settings");
        panel.add(settings);

        // Lambda style ActionListener
        settings.addActionListener(e -> panel.setBackground(new Color(100, 255, 255)));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingTest4 frame = new SwingTest4();
        frame.setSize(100, 100);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Now it's up to you to decide which solution you like most.

Comment: *"Make your starting class inherit from JFrame"*, I disagree, it's better to create an instance of a `JFrame` rather than inherit from it if you're not changing it's behavior

Comment: I aggree that composition is better than inheritance. In fact, most simple Swing applications that I saw worked the way described above: Derive from JFrame (or better JPanel) and do the basic layouting in the constructor. I did not want to frighten the OP with an MVC pattern here.